# CORS+ POST+express.js - as been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: express, http, post, cors

I send query (react app ts)

```
export const setNewComment = async (
  productId: string,
  name: string,
  email: string,
  body: string,
  doSuccessNewComment: (data: string) => void,
  doErrorNewComment: () => void
) => {

  const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `http://localhost:3000/api/products/add-comment/${productId}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    data: {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      body: body,
    }
  }

  await axios(config)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Response', response.data)
      const data: IComment = response.data;
      doSuccessNewComment(data.id);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('Error: ', e.message)
      doErrorNewComment();
    })
```

server API (express ts)

```
productsRouter.post('/add-comment/:id', async (
  req: Request<{ id: string }, {}, CommentAddPayload>,  
  res: Response
) => {

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
  try {
    const commentToAdd = req.body;

    if (!commentToAdd) {
      res.status(400);
      res.send("Comment is empty");
      return;
    }

    const values = [[
       req.params.id,
       commentToAdd.name,
       commentToAdd.email,
       commentToAdd.body,
       uuidv4()
    ]]

    await connection.query<OkPacket>("INSERT INTO comments (product_id, name, email, body, comment_id) VALUES ?", [values]);
   
    res.status(201);
    res.send(commentToAdd);
  } catch (e) {
    throwServerError(res, e);
  }
});
```

I get this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/products/add-comment/6f1a6b96-6cd2-439c-a648-88b9f287f7d2' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

`GET` is working, but `POST` is not.

How to fix it?

Thanks

I'm sending HTTP `POST` query but my browser blocks the answer.

Comment: Rather than implementing CORS by _manually_ setting CORS response headers, you're almost always better off relying on some CORS middleware. Express.js has [one](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html); use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your "GET" went through because i believe you are not sending any headers with it, so no preflight request was made to check with server.
But in your "POST" request you have added some headers, which needs to be checked with server, which is checked with a OPTIONS method.
so create a options and allow origin and content type in it.

OR

If you want to allow cors for list of particular origins, better user this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) for clean code